# Node tabs leading to related nodes

Tags: nodes

I am using a webform to build a basic person node and other related nodes (contact, address) at once.

I'd like to have node tabs ("Contact Infos", "Address") when showing the person node, which are showing the related nodes using url aruments like "/node/1234/contact" or "/node/1234/address".

Do I have to use the hook_menu in a custom module or is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can achieve this using Views by enabling "Show in menu" and selecting "Menu tab". Note that the page URL needs to be `node/%/your-path` and `user/%/your-path` so you can fetch user/node ID from the URL. Is this what you are after?

Comment: Hi! Please read my own answer for my solution which is not far away from yours :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used panels for this. I added a new panel, which has the node with the nid of the webform as only content item in the main content area. I set the menu entry for the panel to "Menu Tab" and set the access rule of the panel to "Show only when node is of type person". This shows the desired tab element when a person node is selected.

For the webform itself I used the `hook_form_alter`with the `$form_id == "webform_client_form_<nid>"` having `<nid>` as the node ID of the webform to set the `#default_value` of the webform field with the data coming from the person node. The ID of the person node I get by using the `arg(1)` function and the loading the node data with `node_load($nid)`.

Hope that helps others.